# Angular 2 - Create Directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-directive, angular8

There was a single dropdown  it was working fine Now I want to make this code reusable, or create Directive because now there are few more dropdowns are added in few more pages

I prefer to make directive, but I am really stuck here

```
<div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
    <div class="menu-text" (click)="hasDropdown($event)">
        Click me
    </div>
    <div class="has-dropdown-view">
         Dropdown contenthere
    </div>
</div>


hasDropdown(event){
  let target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
  this.dropownView = !this.dropownView;
  if( this.dropownView  ){
    target.closest('.has-dropdown').classList.add('has-open')
  }else{
    target.closest('.has-dropdown').classList.remove('has-open')
  }
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fykm75)

**How to implement this click function with the directive 'method'?**

Comment: what is issue in creating directive ?

Comment: How to implement this click function with the directive method ?

Comment: I think there are dozens of articles which you may find useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be a solution for your problem:

```
   import { Directive,ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';


    @Directive({
        selector: '[hasDropdown]'
    })

    export class HasDropdownDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

        }
        @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {

           //Place your code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using bootstrap in your project there is a better way of adding the open class in the dropdown.

Solution Bootstrap 3.3
HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown"
        appDropDown>
      <a href="#"
         class="dropdown-toggle">Manage</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Save Data</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Edit Data</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Directivefile

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, HostBinding, } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropDown]",
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen: boolean = false;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  @HostListener('click') click(eventData: Event) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

**Note**: Above solution uses the HostBinding method,  you can even use the ElementRef for it.

This you automatically inject the class open on the click and you can keep using the same bootstrap template everywhere.